# How to block access to all pages of the website except /blog in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-alias

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/$
```

This code blocks the home page

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/.*$
```

This code blocks all pages

How to get the effect that all pages except one (/blog) are blocked  (404)?

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess by editing your question

Comment: Are you specifically wanting to use mod_alias for this?

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/((?!blog).*)$
```

Comment: This code is blocking everything: home page, subpages and /blog too...

Comment: Oh yes sorry, this will block all pages that are not starting with `/blog`

Comment: @TP999 Since `/blog` is being blocked, you probably have a conflict with existing directives. (?)

Comment: @TP999 This redirect blocks everything except `/blog` and `/blog/foobar` . The reason why it doesn't work on your server is because you are using `RewriteRules` to handle other URLs  and that rule conflicts with this one. If you want to solve this then use a `RewriteRule`. instead of `RedirectMatch` . @anubhava 's solution should definitely work for you.

Answer (score 0):

My full .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RedirectMatch 404 ^/((?!blog).*)$
```

This code is blocking everything: home page, subpages and /blog too.

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the effect that all pages except one (/blog) are blocked (404)?

You may use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if request doesn't start with /blog then return R=404
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+blog[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.
After entering this code on my wordpres error 404 is showing all pages. (it doesn't matter if I put the word "blog" in there or anything else). Only after removing this part:

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+blog[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

All pages are starting to load

Comment: Does it return 404 for `example.com/blog` also?

Comment: Yes, I tested on 2 domains with wordpress and the same everywhere, all pages are blocked, including /blog

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess in question? Is there any other .htaccess?